# Proxy with Capacitor without server [Angular]

Tags: angular, proxy, capacitor

Is it possible to build a capacitor app with a specific proxy file?

Until now I use inside *capacitor.config.json*

```
server: {
    url: 'https://my-domain.com',
    allowNavigation: ["some.stuffs.com"],
}
```

but if *my-domain.com* is down my mobile app will not show anything. So I'm searching a way to have my app completely on mobile device and seems work if I remove *server* from capacitor configuration

Here the problem:
If my app pointing to *my-domain.com* (started on a server with specific proxy-conf) all works well, but if I remove *server* from capacitor configuration capacitor doesn't start my app with proxy conf and my http request not working well

Is there a way to obtain request proxed correctly on my capacitor app without using *server* conf in capacitor.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know without `server configuration`, your mobile app start works like browser application and send request to endpoint from `.env` settings, you can try to serve your app and check into browser network current endpoint, then change `.env` api whatever you want and build the app.

In our app we use `capacitor server configuration` when working local and improve some features, but when we do some product building we remove that configuration

Answer (score 1):

There is no any way to build the app with the proxy file. As per my understanding, you are using a proxy to resolve the CORS error during development. So when you are building APK you can able to set up the network_security_config.xml file under the android/app/src/main/res/XML folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">youar-api.com</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.0.1</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">com</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">net</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">org</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

You can use the above configuration in the file. AndroidManifest file you need to use this file. So when you build your app you will not required the proxy and it will resolve your CORS error.